# php index of item

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$fruit = array('apple','orange','grape');
```

How can I find the index of a specific item, in the above array? (For example, the value 'orange')

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try the [array_search](http://php.net/array_search) function.

From the first example in the manual:

> ```
> <?php
> $array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
>
> $key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
> $key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
> ?>
> ```

**A word of caution**

When comparing the result, make sure to test explicitly for the value `false` using the `===` operator.

Because arrays in PHP are 0-based, if the element you're searching for is the first element in the array, a value of 0 will be returned.

While 0 is a valid result, it's also a falsy value, meaning the following will fail:

```
<?php
    $array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');   

    $key = array_search('blue',$array);

    if($key == false) {
        throw new Exception('Element not found');
    }
?>
```

This is because the `==` operator checks for *equality* (by type-juggling), while the `===` operator checks for *identity*.

Comment: I think doing the if(in_array(. bit should protect me from the problme you noted after "be careful"

Comment: There's a small error in the code, the array is not specified. It should be `array_search('blue', $array)`.

Answer (score 7):

have in mind that, if you think that your search item can be found more than once, you should use [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) because it will return  keys for all matching values, not only the first matching key as [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use array_search.

Look here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: Return Values

Returns TRUE if needle is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.