# How to check if variable is equal to another variable in array

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say if I have this variable `$a = 'test';`

Now let's say I created an array of multiple items like so:

```
$array['hello'] = 'yes';
$array['goodbye'] = 'no';
$array['afternoon'] = 'test';
```

Is it possible to check if any of the items in the array are the same, similar to `isset()`, then to get which item it is equal to it (`$array['afternoon']`)?

Comment: Seems like you're after `array_search`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046908/php-index-of-item

Comment: You can check array has duplicated by this code:  

   ` function array_has_dupes($array) { return count($array) !== count(array_unique($array)); }`

Comment: Thank you that is actually what I was looking for Nick. I didn't know that the function existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `foreach()`

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
 if($key == $a){
  echo $val;
 }
}
```

**Better way**

use `array_key_exists()`

```
if(array_key_exists($a, $array)){
 echo $a;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was in the middle of fixing it to how I need it, but I have updated it.

Comment: I updated my answer, and I didn't realize you were trying to check for duplicate value.